# Columns in a Day (Dojo Toolkit dojox.Calendar)

Tags: javascript, calendar, dojo, dojox.calendar

I have a problem with dojox.calendar features. Briefly, I am trying to place subcolumns into the calendar with "day" as dateInterval. I have read and tried the following link : http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar#sub-columns

```js
colView.set("store", new Memory({data:[
  {
    summary: "My Event",
    startTime: new Date(2013, 0, 1, 10, 0),
    endTime: new Date(2013, 0, 1, 14, 0),
    calendar: "cal1"
  }
]})**)**;

colView.set("subColumns", ["cal1", "cal2"]);
```

#### my dummy code is here

```js
function(parser, ready, Calendar, Observable, Memory, Deferred, ColumnView, ColumnViewSecondarySheet) {
    ready(function() {
            someData = [{
                id: 0,
                summary: "Default Work",
                begin: new Date(2016, 0, 1, 10, 0),
                end: new Date(2016, 0, 1, 12, 0)
            }];

            calendar = new Calendar({
                date: new Date(2007, 10, 21),
                startTimeAttr: "begin",
                endTimeAttr: "end",
                store: new Observable(new Memory({
                    data: someData
                })),
                dateInterval: "month",
                style: "position:relative;width:750px;height:500px"
            }, "someId");

            var colView = calendar.columnView;
            colView.set("subColumns", ["cal1", "cal2"]);

            colView.set("store", new Memory({
                data: [{
                    summary: "My Event",
                    startTime: new Date(2007, 10, 21, 10, 0),
                    endTime: new Date(2007, 10, 21, 11, 0),
                    calendar: "cal1"
                }]
            }));
        )
    }
```

In the result, it shows me the subcolumns in a day, but I cannot place my events to those subcolumns [The screenshot from dummy code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv53t.png) 
How can I solve this issue?

Thank you for your helps and sorry for my English.

Comment: Your date property in the Calendar is 2007 10 21, whereas, someData is for 2016. It is a type error or it is supposed to be like that?

Comment: Hi, i have changed someData like the following : someData = [
                       {
                         summary: "My Event",
                                    startTime: new Date(2007, 10, 22, 10, 0),
                                    endTime: new Date(2007, 10, 22, 11, 0),
                                    calendar: "cal1"
                       }
                       
                     ];      Now it gives me TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined(…) dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1879(anonymous function)

Comment: You have changed the `startTimeAttr` to "begin" and `endTimeAttr` to "end". so your data should be `someData = [ { summary: "My Event", begin: new Date(2007, 10, 22, 10, 0), end: new Date(2007, 10, 22, 11, 0), calendar: "cal1" } ];`

Comment: @TKambi i am very grateful for your attention thank you so much you saved me. Yes attributes were not right, startTime and endTime is not appropriate, but begin and end made it work. I would like to approve as your answer as the correct one but i could not do for the comment section.

Comment: I shall put the comment as Answer then you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date property to is set to 2007 whereas, your data was reflecting the date for 2016.

Also Since you have changed the startTimeAttr and endTimeAttr. your data should reflect accordingly.

```
 function(parser, ready, Calendar,Observable,Memory,Deferred,ColumnView,ColumnViewSecondarySheet){
            ready(function(){
                someData = [
                            {
                              id: 0,
                              summary: "Default Work",
                              begin: new Date(2016, 0, 1, 10, 0),
                              end: new Date(2016, 0, 1, 12, 0)
                            }
                          ];
                          calendar = new Calendar({
                            date: new Date(2007, 10, 21),
                            startTimeAttr: "begin",
                            endTimeAttr: "end",
                            store: new Observable(new Memory({data: someData})),
                            dateInterval: "month",
                            style: "position:relative;width:750px;height:500px"
                          }, "someId");
                          var colView = calendar.columnView;
                            colView.set("subColumns", ["cal1", "cal2"]);
                            colView.set("store", new Memory({data:[
                            {
                               summary: "My Event",
                               begin: new Date(2007, 10, 21, 10, 0),
                               end: new Date(2007, 10, 21, 11, 0),
                               calendar: "cal1"
                             }
                           ]}));
 )}
```